# How to use ENUM as a parameter to a Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

I have a type defined like this in my Prefix.pch file.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ServerType) {
ServerType0 = 0,
ServerType1,
ServerTypeCount
};
```

I have a method declaration like this:

```
+ (NSArray *)allServersForType:(enum ServerType)serverType;
```

But I am getting warning

"Declaration of 'enum ServerType' will not be visible outside of this function"

and worse when I try to pass it like this:

```
    NSArray *servers = [Server allServersForType:ServerTypeCount];
```

I get an error "Argument type 'enum ServerType' is incomplete"

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Rob

Comment: Get rid of `enum` in the parameter type.

Comment: If I do as you suggested, I then get an error "Expected a type"

Comment: As a test, move the enum declaration to its own .h file and import that .h file in whatever class you need it in.

Comment: That worked, but I do not understand why having it included in my Prefix.pch file wouldn't.

Comment: Now trying importing this new .h file in your .pch file.

Comment: Yep, that worked too.  Why not directly though?

Answer (score 10):

You've typedefed the enum so no need to specify `enum` again.

```
+ (NSArray *)allServersForType:(ServerType)serverType;
```

**Update taken from comments:**

Add the declaration of the enum to the .h file of the class that declares this `allServersForType:` method.

Comment: If I do as you suggested, I then get an error "Expected a type"

Comment: @Rob Press Command-B or run your project, and it should go away.

Comment: @Rob As rmaddy suggested, try moving the declaration to it's own .h file and import that .h file.

Answer (score -6):

Your method should really be this:

```
+(NSArray*)allServersForType:(ServerType)serverType;
```

To call it just do :

```
NSArray *servers = [Server allServersForType:ServerTypeCount];// Server here is your class name
```

Comment: There is no need to repeat an answer.